# Validating Tkinter Entry For Digits, Floats, Some Operators

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

I am a newbie, please ignore if i show some noobness !
I am trying to create a tkinter calculator. In My entry box,  I am trying to validate Numbers, Float, some opeands like +,-,*,/.

I wrote this code, but it would accept NO ENTRY, even number.
Can you please correct this code?

**Function For Validation:-**

```
def correct(inp):
    if inp.isdigit():
        return True
    elif inp is "":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**My entry box:-**

```
mainFrame = Frame(bg='#c7ecee', width=1580, height=400)
resultFrame = Frame(mainFrame, bg='#badc58')
mainFrame.pack_propagate(False)
mainFrame.pack(pady=30)
resultFrame.place(x=710, y=260)

result = Entry(resultFrame, font=(
    "Segoe UI bold", 56), bg='#E6E6E6', bd=0, justify=RIGHT, )#insertontime=0
result.focus_set()
reg = root.register(correct)
result.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%p'))
result.pack()
```

Comment: Please make the following correction to your code: `result.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))`. Notice I have used `%P` instead of `%p`.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `inp` is what you're expecting it to be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validating Tkinter Entry Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63664283/validating-tkinter-entry-box)